# Unmet Dependencies while installing python packages

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using the following code to install few python packages:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev build-essential
```

But it throwing me unmet dependencies error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-dev : Depends: python (= 2.7.11-1) but 2.7.13-1 is to be installed
              Depends: python2.7-dev (>= 2.7.11-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 python-setuptools : Depends: python-pkg-resources (= 20.7.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                     Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried these 2 steps, but still having the error:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
```

Comment: the problem is that the package you want to install needs packege with version that your repository cannot give you. you cannot fix it with apt commands. try to find repository that have all the dependencies met

Comment: @Tamar: Thanks for your suggestion! But how to find these repositories.

Comment: I don't know. I found a question similar to yours, three months old w/o an answer. you can try to upgrade ubuntu, or install the packages you want with `pip`